# help!-WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI port [80] does not match this roscore [11311]

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, roscore, ros-hostname

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to connect to the turtlebot and I think I accidentally changed the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME. Now, whenever I run roscore I get this:

WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI port [80] does not match this roscore [11311]

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63897/help!-warning:-ros_master_uri-port-%5B80%5D-does-not-match-this-roscore-%5B11311%5D/) by [turtlebotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4957/turtlebotnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I figured it out.. Just changed my ROS_MASTER_URI to localhost. ie., export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

---

Originally posted by [turtlebotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4957/turtlebotnewbie/) with karma: 78 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/18121/yaser/) on 2014-05-17**:
good job !